# Swift - Computed Property Return

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

I have array of dictionaries that I will use for cells in collectionView. I'm new to swift, so I try to find the best way to store that.

Now I use this code:

```
var collectionViewData: [collectionViewStruct] = {
    var cell_1 = collectionViewStruct()
    cell_1.title = "..."
    cell_1.text = "..."
    cell_1.firstColor = "C68CF2"
    cell_1.secondColor = "EFA8CA"

    var cell_2 = collectionViewStruct()
    cell_2.title = "..."
    cell_2.text = "..."
    cell_2.firstColor = "C68CF2"
    cell_2.secondColor = "EFA8CA"

    return [cell_1, cell_2]
}()
```

Is there a way not to write every var in return?

How to return all the variables at once?

Or maybe there is a better way to store this data?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Why is `suggestions` an array? Also where are the other variables, i see only one?

Comment: this is a closure not computed property

Comment: If it's a constant, why does it have to be computed? Computed properties act as observers. They can change every time. Consider using `let`.

Comment: I'm new to Swift and trying to find the best way to store the array of dictionaries

Comment: Can you update your question and state the purpose of `suggestions`? We could offer better help that way.

Comment: Just updated. I mentioned that this is the data that I want to use in collectioView

Comment: See my answer, you can just set the colors as constants within your struct and just use the default constructor to start a constant `collectionViewData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the suggestions data is never changing, just use the following struct:

```
struct collectinView {
    let title: String
    let text: String
    let firstColor = "C68CF2"
    let secondColor = "EFA8CA"
}

let collectionViewData = [
    collectionView(title: "...", text: "..."),
    collectionView(title: "other Title", text: "Other text")]
```

Comment: Colors are different for each cell, but yeah, I think, this way is much better, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

For achieving this you can use a private property and return that instead like:

```
    private var _suggestions: [suggestionsStruct] = [suggestionsStruct]()
    var suggestions: [suggestionsStruct] {
    get{

        if _suggestions.count > 0{
            var suggestion_1 = suggestionsStruct()
            suggestion_1.title = "..."
            suggestion_1.text = "..."
            suggestion_1.firstColor = "C68CF2"
            suggestion_1.secondColor = "EFA8CA"
            _suggestions.append(suggestion_1)
        }else{
            var suggestion_1 = suggestionsStruct()
            suggestion_1.title = "..."
            suggestion_1.text = "..."
            suggestion_1.firstColor = "C68CF2"
            suggestion_1.secondColor = "EFA8CA"
            _suggestions = [suggestion_1]
        }
        return _suggestions
    }
}
```